# How to increase Vuforia camera resolution?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I have a project that requires Vuforia to use the highest camera resolution possible for detection and tracking irregardless of final FPS. But I only get the resolution 1280 x 720 on Samsung Galaxy S23.

I have searched this question for answer in the Vuforia forums and found something such as "At present there is no way to increase the camera resolution.", and also "there is no specific solution to this; on certain devices the camera resolution is limited". These answers were from a long time ago. Is there a way to set the resolution of the Camera with Vuforia now? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to set the camera resolution. Instead, the Vuforia Engine has camera modes that you can set to adjust the image quality over performance. Use `SetCameraMode(CameraMode.MODE_OPTIMIZE_QUALITY)` for a higher resolution and image quality.

See [Working with Camera in Unity](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/platform-support/working-camera-unity) or the [API library](https://developer.vuforia.com/library/sites/default/files/references/unity/group__CameraDeviceGroup.html#gac6e73fe6ce68e10b0acd6d2312bdbb35).

Hope it helps,

Comment: All right, thank you for your answer sincerely!